# How to get changing RSSI of BLE in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, proximity, rssi

I am using Kontakt beacon device & testing ble on nexus 5. When I tested iPad as a beacon device I am able to find out the services & characteristics with the help of the code given on android developer site. But now  I want to do some actions depending on the distance of the mobile from the beacon device. So I tried to detect how far is the mobile from the beacon device like iOS CLBeacon.Proximity (CLProximityFar, CLProximityNear, CLProximityImmideate & CLProximityUnknown). I searched but not able to find out like this in android. So decided to do some actions depending on the rssi. But problem is whatever rssi I am getting first time i.e at the time of mobile detect beacon device is not changing even if I move near to beacon device or went far away from it.

If any one had idea how to get the changing rssi in the android then please share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you checked the never changed rssi as you described, via a existed APP or writing codes by yourself?

but from the code, it's quite straight forward, I put a core code in Android 5.0,

```
//get your device's BT adapter
mBluetoothAdapter = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
mLescanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(scanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();
mLescanner.startScan(this.mLeScanCallback);
```

And the callback is like this, and you can get the real time rssi in the function:

```
this.mLeScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        int realTimeRssiYouWant = result.getRssi(); 
    }
}
```